# bash pipe multiple outputs as input to other command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, pipe

I am noob with shell script and I am trying to pass multiple arguments to an command.
I have a **urls.txt** file that looks as below

```
name1,http://url1
name2,http://url2
name3,http://url3
name4,http://url4
```

with the below command I am able to get output after splitting by comma

```
cat urls.txt | cut -d ',' -f1
cat urls.txt | cut -d ',' -f2
```

The first one gives the name1, name2, etc and second one gives http://url1 http://url2.
what I wanted to do was pipe both of them as a variable to a third command where I can use both of them.

Any ideas or suggestions are highly appreciated?

Comment: This looks like a shell script question, not specifically related to Ubuntu. You might want to ask this question on https://stackoverflow.com/. Please explain what you want to achieve. What does your "third command" do? Your description "pipe both of them as a variable to a third command" does not make much sense. The terms *pipe*  and * variable* are different things. A pipe is a data stream which can be split into lines or words.

Comment: see [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Field_splitting.2C_whitespace_trimming.2C_and_other_input_processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ while IFS=, read nam url ;do echo "name:$nam, url:$url" ; done <urls.txt 
name:name1, url:http://url1
name:name2, url:http://url2
name:name3, url:http://url3
name:name4, url:http://url4
```